# Delete users from ldap using java code

Tags: java, ldap, websphere, ldap-query, tivoli

How can I delete users from LDAP? I need to login to the Websphere portal through a non admin username. I have passed the administrative credentials in the code as mentioned below, however I get this error:

```
 javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; Remaining name: 'uid=LM00828-00,cn=users,o=dealers,dc=india,dc=company,dc=com'
```

Java code is as follows:

```
public void deactivate{
String proUrl = "ldap://hostname:portnumber" ;
String connectiontype = "simple" ;

String AdminDn = "uid=portaladmin,cn=users,o=admins,dc=india,dc=comapny,dc=com" ;
String password = "password" ;

Hashtable<String, String> environmentVar = new Hashtable<String, String>() ;

environmentVar.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
environmentVar.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  proUrl) ;
environmentVar.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,  connectiontype) ;
environmentVar.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,  AdminDn ) ;
environmentVar.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,  password) ;
DirContext dirContext = new InitialDirContext(environmentVar) ;  
deleteUser(dirContext);
}

public void deleteUser(DirContext context) {

try {
context.destroySubcontext("uid=LM00828-00,cn=users,o=dealers,dc=india,dc=company,dc=com");
NamingEnumeration list = context.list("");

// Go through each item in list
while (list.hasMore()) {
NameClassPair nc = (NameClassPair)list.next();
ApplicationLogger.debug(nc);
}

// Close the context when we're done
context.close();

} catch (NamingException e) {
ApplicationLogger.error(e);
}

}
```

Comment: You logged in to LDAP as a user who doesn't have delete permissions. As the exception states. Clearly.

Comment: I'm logging in to the Websphere portal as a non admin user not LDAP. However the credentials that I have passed to the environment variable is the LDAP administrative user who has delete permissions.

Comment: Assuming that your LDAP is AD, did you try to login to windows with your portaladmin user and delete that object from AD? This would ensure that user has correct privileges.

Comment: Yes. With portaladmin user it deletes properly. However, I need to login with a user that is not portaladmin.

Comment: You need to login as a user that has delete permission. Period.

Comment: How do I set delete permissions to a non administrative user?